# Not in scope: data constructor `Movement'

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want to make a function, that changes certain value according to the passed letter. (These are basically given directions: East, West....)

The code is :

```
data Movement  = N Int | S Int | E Int | W Int deriving (Eq, Show)

step :: Movement -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
step (Movement x h) (y, z) 
    | x == N = (y, z+h)
    | x == S = (y, z-h)
    | x == W = (y-h, z)
    | x == E = (y+h, z)
```

An Example:

```
step (N 1) (239, 578) == (239, 579)
step (S 1) (240, 578) == (240, 577)
step (W 1) (239, 578) == (238, 578)
step (E 1) (239, 577) == (240, 577)
step (N 61) (239, 578) == (239,639)
step (N 2) (-4, 0) == (-4, 2)
step (E 1) (-4, 0) == (-3, 0)
step (S (-61)) (239, 578) == (239,639)
```

I am keep getting

> Not in scope: data constructor `Movement'

error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Movement` is a type, not a value. You can't use that in patterns.

Further, `N` and other constructors are functions, and you can't `==` functions.

You need to use pattern matching instead, and forget guards.

```
step :: Movement -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
step (N h) (y,z) = ...
step (S h) (y,z) = ...
step (W h) (y,z) = ...
step (E h) (y,z) = ...
```

Alternatively, refactor your type:

```
data Direction = N | S | E | W deriving (Eq, Show)
data Movement  = Movement Direction Int deriving (Eq, Show)

step :: Movement -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
step (Movement x h) (y,z) 
    | x == N = (y, z+h)
    | x == S = (y, z-h)
    | x == W = (y-h, z)
    | x == E = (y+h, z)
```

Now your code works, since `Movement` is also a data constructor, and `N` and friends are no longer functions. I would still prefer to avoid guards, though, and use

```
step :: Movement -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
step (Movement N h) (y,z) = (y, z+h)
step (Movement S h) (y,z) = (y, z-h)
step (Movement W h) (y,z) = (y-h, z)
step (Movement E h) (y,z) = (y+h, z)
```